# Maximum requests (total processing) that can be handled by java servlets using Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I am developing a web server which will take input string and will perform a back ground process (3-5 minutes). I got to know that `apache tomcat` can handle 200 requests/s. But, what happens if my server is stacking all those requests and processing for the 3-5 minutes, like the total running threads will be `36000` (say for 3 minutes *200)? 
So what would be the better solution to deal with?
Is it a good Idea to implement a Queuing System? I never implemented one.
How, in general, `web servers` deal with the load?

Answer (score 0):

5 minutes is a lot of time to process a request. I agree with an external queue system to avoid overflow the heap ... you may use asynchronous process also.

BTW Tomcat can handle much more than 200r/s but anyway i think that 5 minutes processing can harm your performance if you use a sinchronous process and you have significant amount of traffic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please provide me a reference to implement Queue system.

Comment: You can use a standalone HornetQ, ActiveMQ, or any other. For something less heavy you can use Jesque backed by Redis store ... instead a full JMS platform this is an external Job Executor system ... i've used it in similar situation that you have.